# what is the difference between "gwan_1" and "gwan -w 1"?

Tags: g-wan, cpu-cores

In the gwan.ch/en_timeline.html stated that,
renaming gwan to gwan_1 is to start gwan with one worker.

what is the difference between gwan_1 and gwan -w 1  ?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the documentation, there is no difference in functionality.

One way (renaming the executable) allows a permanent choice while the command-line switch allows quick tests.

Historically, these features were introduced for G-WAN tests on machines with thousands of CPU Cores. Those tests led to rewrite of some portions of the G-WAN kernel to get higher performance. The result is G-WAN v3.8.

Comment: No, there are no gwan 3.8 or 3.10 available, when it will be released?

Comment: Registered users have access to beta versions, either at the Enterprise level or because they need specific features that they initiated. The next public release will come in a couple of weeks.

Comment: And don't you think or g-wan team that this information should be on the official site?

Because now there are information (not completed) on how to run php or c# and it is even advertised on home page, but no way to use it for the public, this isn't right.